# Ramsey Uuid is not working on newly installed laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I have installed laravel 5.4 and Ramsey Uuid was already in it and I tried to use it. Following is the code

**HomeController.php**

```
use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;
use Ramsey\Uuid\Exception\UnsatisfiedDependencyException;
$uuid1 = Uuid::uuid1(); 
echo $uuid1->toString() . "\n";
```

But it is giving me following error.

> Caught exception: When calling
>   Ramsey\Uuid\Converter\Time\DegradedTimeConverter::calculateTime on a
>   32-bit system, Moontoast\Math\BigNumber must be present.

I have installed ramsey/uuid version 3.6.1

Any suggestions please, what could be the solution?

Comment: Did you see that? https://github.com/ramsey/uuid/issues/76

Comment: You can add requirement in composer https://github.com/moontoast/math It might help but not sure

Comment: Yes I read https://github.com/ramsey/uuid/issues/76 but did not understand what I need to do. I cloned from git one week ago

Comment: Seems like that was a bug and then they have fixed it. Anyway if message was 'must present library...' try to require it

Comment: Yes I have installed https://github.com/moontoast/math and it worked thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with Laravel 5.4. You should install https://github.com/moontoast/math by executing

```
composer require "moontoast/math"
```

The reason this error occurred is that you environment not supported large integers (32 bit operation system etc). You can find this explanation in code of [ramsey/uuid](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid/blob/8d2bab3c17c6325551ffd5562105a95e21c049de/src/Converter/Time/DegradedTimeConverter.php#L21)